# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasPermission' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm making a discord bot, I learned v12 of discord.js, When I was creating a anti spam command in discord, and then when i was finished, I ran the command and it gave the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasPermission' of undefined` and here is my code. its a command handler by the way

```
    const AntiSpam = require("./spam.js");
    
    const cooldown = new Set();
    
    client.on("message", async (message, member) => {
    
        if (!message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) {
    
          if(message.author.bot) return;
          if (!message.guild) return;
          if(!message.guild.members.cache.get(client.user.id).hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return;
         if(!message.member) return;
         let spam = await db.fetch(`spamEngel_${message.guild.id}`) 
         if(!spam) return;
         AntiSpam(client, message);
        }
    });
```

Comment: If you have 4 `if`s in a row that all do the same thing, you may want to consider combining them with an or (`||`)

Comment: Either `message` or `member` is undefined. That's why giving this error

Answer (score 0):

`message.member` Represents the author of the message as a guild member, otherwise it will be undefined, then you should look for `message.author` in that case. Take a look intoo their docs https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member

Comment: its gives a error > message.author.hasPermission is not a function

Comment: You can't check for permissions when the author isn't a guild member.
User(https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) doesn't hava the hasPermissions function

Comment: And guildMember will always be undefined on DM, it has to be a message sent in a guild channel

Answer (score 0):

You defined a member in `client.on("message", async (message, member) =>`. Delete a member from this line and then `member` will be defined by the message with `message.member`, other than that your code seems good! Remember that you can reduce number of "ifs" by putting everything in one if and connecting it with `&&`, example `if( x!= 2 && x > 0)`